# Triggering Hover Events After Fading in an Element Under the Cursor

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

### Description:

I have an element that is hidden on page load. After a few moments, it fades in. If the user's cursor is on top of where that element loads in, I would like for it to still trigger hover events (e.g. `.mouseenter()` and `.mouseleave()`) without requiring the user to further move their mouse.

In the example provided below, upon page load, place your cursor inside the red box. ***Note that this red box is only here for demonstrative purposes to show you where to place your cursor.*** After a few seconds, a kitten will fade into view. If you move your mouse, you will trigger scaling effects and upsize the kitten to 150%. If you don't, it will never trigger the mouse event and the kitten will not grow. How can I resolve this?

***Edit***: It appears to trigger automatically in Firefox 31, but not in Chrome 36 or IE.

### Fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/6xw8Z/1/

### Code

```
setTimeout(function() {
    $('#kitty').fadeIn('slow');
}, 3000);

$('#kitty').mouseenter(function() {
    $(this).css({
        'transform': 'scale(1.5)',
        'transition': 'transform 500ms'
    });
}).mouseleave(function() {
    $(this).css({
        'transform': 'scale(1)',
        'transition': 'transform 500ms'
    });
});
```

Comment: just replace `'#kitty'` with `'#border'`

Comment: My apologies; this was poor planning on my part. ``#border`` only exists for demonstrative purposes in the fiddle; it is not actually there otherwise. I will update my post to specify.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to keep track of were the mouse is, using the `mousemove` event and then check if the mouse is within the elements bounds once the `fadeIn` is done.

http://jsfiddle.net/6xw8Z/5/

**jQuery**

```
var mouseX = 0,
    mouseY = 0;

setTimeout(function() {
    $('#kitty').fadeIn('slow', function() {

        var thisOffset = $(this).offset(),
            thisWidth = $(this).outerWidth(),
            thisHeight = $(this).outerHeight();

        if(mouseX >= thisOffset.left && mouseX <= (thisOffset.left + thisWidth) && mouseY >= thisOffset.top && mouseY <= (thisOffset.top + thisHeight)) {

            $(this).trigger('mouseenter');

        }

        $('body').unbind('mousemove');

    });
}, 3000);

$('#kitty').mouseenter(function() {
    $(this).css({
        'transform': 'scale(1.5)',
        'transition': 'transform 500ms'
    });
}).mouseleave(function() {
    $(this).css({
        'transform': 'scale(1)',
        'transition': 'transform 500ms'
    });
});

$('body').mousemove(function(event) {

   mouseX = event.pageX;
   mouseY = event.pageY;

});
```

Or if you wish the `mouseenter` to be triggered as soon as the `fadeIn` starts.

http://jsfiddle.net/6xw8Z/6/

**jQuery**

```
var mouseX = 0,
    mouseY = 0;

setTimeout(function() {
    $('#kitty').fadeIn('slow');
    var thisOffset = $('#kitty').offset(),
        thisWidth = $('#kitty').outerWidth(),
        thisHeight = $('#kitty').outerHeight();

    if(mouseX >= thisOffset.left && mouseX <= (thisOffset.left + thisWidth) && 
       mouseY >= thisOffset.top && mouseY <= (thisOffset.top + thisHeight)) {

        $('#kitty').trigger('mouseenter');

    }

    $('body').unbind('mousemove');
}, 3000);

$('#kitty').mouseenter(function() {
    $(this).css({
        'transform': 'scale(1.5)',
        'transition': 'transform 500ms'
    });
}).mouseleave(function() {
    $(this).css({
        'transform': 'scale(1)',
        'transition': 'transform 500ms'
    });
});

$('body').mousemove(function(event) {

   mouseX = event.pageX;
   mouseY = event.pageY;

});
```

Comment: Thank you for two wonderful, working answers. I was a little afraid it would involve tracking the mouse coordinates, so I was hoping to avoid it - I had always heard that doing this was taxing on the browser. Do you know what kind of a performance hit this method requires, or is it insignificant?

Comment: You're welcome. Not sure about the performance. But when you mention it, you don't need to keep tracking the mouse coordinates after the check is done. Let me update the answers and take care of that by unbinding the `mousemove` listner as soon as it's not needed anymore!